# limit point of union and intersection of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ be a collection of sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and let $S=\bigcup_{A \in F} A$ and $T=\bigcap_{A \in F} A$

Then prove or give counter Example for the following statements

1. If $x$ is a limit point of $S$ , then $x$ is a limit point of atleast one set $A$ in $F$
2. If $x$ is a limit point of $T$ , then $x$ is a limit point of aeach set $A$ in $F$

I think the 1st is false and 2nd is true. Am I right and how to prove or disprove it ? 
Please help.

Comment: For 1: can't you just take some collection of one-point sets?

Comment: It is standard to use \cup in expressions like $A\cup B$ or $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$, and \bigcup in expressions like $\displaystyle\bigcup_{A\in F} A$.  I edited the question accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering when to use \big.. . Very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, a single example is enough.  For every number $x>0$, let $A_x=[x,\infty)$.  Then $0$ is a limit point of $\bigcup_{x>0} A_x$, but not a limit point of any of the sets $A_x$.

For the second one, every open neighborhood of $x$ contains some point of $T$ other than $x$.  Every point in $T$ is a member of EVERY $A\in F$.  Therefore, for every $A\in F$, every open neighborhood of $x$ contains some point of $A$ other than $x$.  Thus $x$ is a limit point of $A$.